# How to take multiple inputs of different data types on same line in python 2? can't use map() function as input has mixed data

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

For ex: i want to take input as A 50 60 70. A is student name and next three numbers are marks of A in 3 subjects. Help me in storing data as above. I have to collect that data for n students.

```
n=input()
for i in range(0,n):
    St=raw_input(), Eng,Mat,Sci=map(int,raw_input().split())
    print st
    print Eng,Mat,Sci
```

Error:

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "main.py", line 3                                                                                                                                                                                      
    St=raw_input(), Eng,Mat,Sci=map(int,raw_input().split())                                                                                                                                                  
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: if it's always passed with schema: "studnet, grade1, grade2, grade3" this is fastest way - 

`st, eng, mat, sci = raw_input().split()`

Comment: @Howaboutnope: Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep multiple lines of code in one line by separating them with a `;`, as long as they're in the same indent level. And since it's python 2, shouldn't `n=int(raw_input())`?

```
n=int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,n):
    St=raw_input(); Eng,Mat,Sci=map(int,raw_input().split())
    print st
    print Eng,Mat,Sci
```

But...this isn't a good practice, as it makes your code harder to read. You should separate them on different lines.

```
n=int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,n):
    St=raw_input()
    Eng,Mat,Sci=map(int,raw_input().split())
    print st
    print Eng,Mat,Sci
```

Comment: any specific reason to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`? Other than error checking

Comment: @kuro thanks for reminding me to convert n to int. and for why use `raw_input()`, have you ever heard of `eval()` is [dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)? Well, it is, and `input()` in python2 is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`

Answer (score 0):

In Python,**split() function** works for taking multiple inputs as a list data type. If you need int,char or string type data then you need to apply **typecasting** of Python.In the solution,I am using the same approach.

```
n=int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,n):
     s=str(raw_input())
     St,Eng,Mat,Sci=raw_input().split()
     Eng=int(Eng)
     Mat=int(Mat)
     Sci=int(Sci)
     print St,s
     print Eng,Mat,Sci
```

Comment: An explanation, what a code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the job in python 3.

```
n = int(input())
marks = {}
for i in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    marks[name] = scores
```